# Changing text color of list view in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-text-color

I am trying to change the text color of a listview in Android. Can anyone please give me a heads up on how it's done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use themes to set the styles for your `TextViews`.
From the [Android dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then to use it:

```
<TextView style="@style/CodeFont" />
```

**Edit - based on comment**

You asked about multiple color in the same TextView:
Your best bet is to use html. Which you set in a TextView for example:

`myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p style="color:red">" + someText + "</p><p style="color:blue">" + someOtherText + "</p>"));`

Comment: HI, the question asked is How to change the color of text inside the list view. could you please explain how to do that.

Comment: If you want multiple bits of text of different colours then your best bet is to use html. Which you set in a TextView like this:

Comment: @Tristan.... can we uset font from assest folder using style code.. means we do not have to do run time coding... for typeface...

Answer (score 22):

Yes possible

please add a separate layout with the textview

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


 <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and change the 
****android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1****
to and pass the textview id like this

new ArrayAdapter(this,
                **R.layout.layoutfilename**,**android.R.id.text1**,userList);

Comment: yes, but didn't you mean **R.layout.layoutfilename, R.id.text1** ?

Answer (score -6):

Have you tried something like `android:textColor="#ffffff"` in your layout.xml file?