# How can I change Item ListView color with onActivityResult?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have the activity A with listView and the activity B with form. I touch in a Item from activity A and call the form from activity B. Eg. I touch in a Item "Laura" and open a form about her, after I fill the form and finish the activity B I return the string "Laura" and I want to change Item ListView color from Laura. How can I do that?

Comment: Try checking this StackOverflow link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564789/change-listviews-textcolor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a boolean to check if u made some changed on Laura account, so it will look something like this :

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Check which request we're responding to
if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACCOUNT_LAURA) {
    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // The user changed Laura account.
        boolean isAccountChanged=  data.getBooleanExtra("isAccountChanged", false);
        if (isAccountChanged) {
          ListView listView = new ListView(this);
          // Get the view associated with Laura, and change the background color.
          ((View) listView.getItemAtPosition(position)).setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
                 listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

        // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
    }
  }
}
```

Also you can use this onListItemCLick, which you can set on your ListView:

```
View lastTouchedView;

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
 lastTouchedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
 v.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
 lastTouchedView = v;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer, but I can't change listView color in the onActivityResult, id you try a simple listView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black), you wont get it!

Comment: You need to reset the list view adapter. Either use 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or just listView.setAdapter(new Adapter() ...)

Answer (score 0):

return something else besides "Laura". maybe return an object in a bundle? 
OnActivityResult() isn't just limited to primitive types. Experiment with that and see what you can accomplish =)